# Is it safe to exceed the power supply current rating for a pump?

Tags: charger

I want to buy a water pump that has capacity `DC 3.5V-9V 3W` which by my 5V USB charger makes 0.6A. My charger has output 5W 1A. Is it safe to exceed the 0.6A value by 0.4A?

Comment: The pump will only draw the amount of current it needs, the power supply does not force more current trough the load then it requires. A pump might draw a current spike at start-up tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s never wise to exceed rated current with surges without storage capacity depending inrush current limits.

The pump power may rise >500% on startup and drop to 5/9 th of 3W max at 5V depending on load or lower.  It is unknown how your load will react unless you test it with a flyback protection diode to opposite power rail.

Measuring pump DCR will tell you the start resistance and surge current.

Comment: thanks for the answer! So if I understand it good, it will takes only the current it needs, but it can instantly go high on a start so it could broke?

Comment: It is unknown how much usb surge capacity you have.